# How to centralize refetch and update logic in Apollo Client

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

When performing mutations it is possible to value  `refetchQueries` `update` and `updateQueries` options to provide reaction to current app query results.
However, i'd like to centralize reactive implementation, so various app components performing mutations will not have to deal - likely redundantly - with mutation|query relations.
I noticed `ApolloClient` constructor's options: `ApolloClientOptions.defaultOptions.mutate.*` which are functions that give chance to return `RefetchQueryDescription`s or operate on `DataProxy` in response of a `ExecutionResult` argument alone which, in my opinion, does not provide enough context for the function implementation, as the triggering `Operation` would also be necessary.
I then took in consideration `ApolloLink` which seems a perfect candidate, having the chance to hook and override the `Operation` object, but unfortunately `Operation` object does not define any of those *reacting* properties.
Any advice on how to implement my use case?